# Android Material Design

Tags: android, material-design

I have a linear layout with a horizontal orientation. In the horizontal orientation I have 3 widgets `ImageButton`, `Edittext` and `Fabbutton`.

How can I align `Imagebutton` to the left and its padding to left,right,top and bottom should be same?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"`enter code here`
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.ashwini.chatscreen.MainActivity">

   <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"></include>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
       <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:background="@drawable/ic_down_arrow"
           android:id="@id/downButton"/>
       <EditText
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:paddingLeft="30dp"
           android:layout_weight="3"
           >
           <requestFocus></requestFocus>
       </EditText>


       <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_send_message_button"
           android:layout_weight="0.86"/>
   </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can't understand what you need. Can you show a picture what you have and what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/down_arrow"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_send_button_icon"
                android:layout_weight="0.86"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: Preview here]